# Found two representations of same collection - @ElementCollection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I've got two classes in this case. One embeds a Memo class:

```
@Entity
class Project {
  ...
  @Embed
  private Memo memo;
  ...
}
```

And the embeddable Memo class:

```
@Embeddable
public class Memo implements Serializable {

  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @CollectionTable(name = "MEMO_LINES")
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "TITLE",nullable = false)
  @Column(name = "VAL",nullable = false)
  private Map<String, String> memoLines = new HashMap<String, String>();

}
```

When flushing a merged instance of Project I'm getting the error message:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection: Project.memo.memoLines
```

However, it doesn't occur when not flushing the entity.

This error seems typically to occur for one/many relationships. But that's not the case here. Neither is this the Play! framework. Just regular Spring/JPA/Hibernate.

Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.1.4.Final, JDK7u7, Linux 64.

Anybody had this before ? Or any rational explanation of what the error actually means ?

**UPDATE: It's related to flush()**

It appears it works if there's only one flush. If intermediary flushes are done, then it'll throw the exception. A messy solution is to flush at the exit of the first method persisting data. Enclosed method calls for persisting check a threadlocal variable to see if they should flush.

But there's certainly a much better way to this...